# Spyder IDE doesn't see pyspark module

Tags: python, python-2.7, apache-spark, spyder

I have a trouble with importing pyspark in Spyder IDE on Ubuntu 14.04. While I can easily type `import pyspark` in python terminal, then if I type import pyspark in Spyder's console it produces me a following error:

```
>>> import pyspark
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    ImportError: No module named pyspark
```

I exported required paths in `.bashrc`:

```
export SCALA_HOME=/usr/local/src/scala/scala-2.10.4
export PATH=$SCALA_HOME/bin:$PATH

export SPARK_HOME=/usr/local/spark
export PATH=$SPARK_HOME/bin:$PATH

export PYTHONPATH=$SPARK_HOME/python/:$PYTHONPATH
export PYTHONPATH=$SPARK_HOME/python/lib/py4j-0.9-src.zip:$PYTHONPATH

export PATH=/usr/local/spark/bin:$PATH
```

Any ideas, what I have to do to use `import pyspark` in Spyder/PyCharm?
It works on my office computer with windows, but I want to use it on my home computer with ubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partially solved - I have to run Spyder IDE from terminal with

```
spyder
```

Then I'm able to do

```
import pyspark
```

in Spyder console. But if I use the launcher to start Spyder, then it still gives me the same error as descripted above. That partial solution works with PyCharm too.

Comment: (*Spyder dev here*) This is because Spyder doesn't load your environment variables when it's run from the Launcher (a shortcoming that we plan to fix in the future). That's why you have to always start it from the terminal (at least in your case).